# Javascript Loop with delay

Tags: javascript

When i am using this command it's after the time passes it's starts spamming without stopping. I want it to do it every [x] milliseconds

```
setInterval(function() {
    bot.sendMessage(message, "Text")
}, 600000);
});
```

(Discord.js)

Comment: You seem to have a spare `});` lying around.

Comment: How are you setting this interval?

Comment: @Dresden: Semi-colons are optional (but highly encouraged)  in JavaScript.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Yeah I just realized that after I put it and it would cause a different error if it were a legitimate problem.

Comment: http://puu.sh/pfATk/edc89f3edf.png
Here it shown how does it spam

Rocket Hazmat: 600000 are the milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.info('hi');
}, 600);
```

May be you have extra pair of closing parenthesis
http://jsbin.com/jihigonixa/edit?html,js,console,output

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: Did you check the jsbin link I posted. Its working there already
 http://jsbin.com/jihigonixa/edit?html,js,console,output

Not sure why the downvote and whats not working

Answer (score 0):

The implementation are correctly and you may have something wrong in your function `bot.sendMessage(message, "Text")`.

> You can see the W3C documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-setinterval

See an example:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   console.log('Hello'); 
}, 3000);
```

This print each 3 seconds the message `Hello`.

Comment: I am using node and discord.js. Well it's correct because the text shows but it's just spamming until it's gets blocked by the server

Comment: You're calling this code more than once? We have to understand a little better since the implementation of the setInterval is correct.

Comment: Do you need to print a message only once time?

Comment: So, for this you need to use the `setTimeout` function instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: it's sending 2 times the message

Comment: Only if you call two times! Because It's impossible to `setTimeout` execute one more once.

Comment: Well i have that 
`setInterval(function(){
 var setgamearrayr = setgamearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * setgamearray.length)];
 bot.setPlayingGame(setgamearrayr);
}, 15000); `

but this is not the same wierd thanks anyway

Comment: You use the `setInverval` again... Her is a loop with a interval based on milliseconds. Your questions are a little confused :o

Comment: I asked someone and he explained me why is doing that.